# How to read a file separated by tabs into a struct

Tags: c++

How do you read a file formated like this below seperated by tabs into a struct?
this is the code i have so far i cant get it to work. i can get a whole line in but then how would i seperate the bits of data out???

```
New England Patriots    6   2       .750    3-2 3-0 1-0 1   
Buffalo Bills       5   2       .714    4-0 1-2 1-0 1
```

```
ifstream inFile;

string name1;
string conference1;
string division1;
unsigned short wins1;
unsigned short losses1;
float pct1;

int i = 0;
int count = 0;
// this declares the strings we need 
string line = "";
int a = 0;
string temp = "";

inFile.open(filename.c_str());

if (!inFile) {
    cerr << "Unable to open file" << filename;
    exit(1);   // call system to stop
}
if (inFile) {

    while (inFile.good())
    {
        //std::getline(inFile, line, '\t'); this is how you get line skipping tabs 

        std::getline(inFile, line);
        cout << line;
        cout << endl;
        teams[a].raw = line;
        //cout << teams[a].raw;
        //cout << endl;
        //  teams[a].name = line;

        teams[a].position = a + 1;
        a++;
    }
    cout << teams[20].raw;
    cout << endl;
    cout << a - 1;
    cout << endl;
}
inFile.close();

struct NFL {
    string name;
    string conference;
    string division;
    unsigned short wins;
    string win;
    unsigned short losses;
    string lose;
    float pct;
    string per;
    string home;
    string road;

    string raw;
    int position;
};

struct ExpectedChar { char expected; };

// read a character from a stream and check it has the expected value
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, const ExpectedChar& e)
{
    char c;
    if (in >> c)
        if (c != e.expected)  // failed to read expected character
            in.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    return in;
}

// read a struct pass from a stream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, NFL& p)
{
    ExpectedChar tab{ '\t' };
    in >> p.name >> tab >> p.serviceTime >> tab >> p.classType;
    return in;
}
```

Comment: i think im close to the right idea

Comment: Parse the input by string by tabs then pass the vector as an argument to the struct constructor?

Comment: This is probably a job for [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok). It's primitive, but it works.

Comment: trying both these things reading about strtok

Comment: As you are using C++, there is absolutely no need to dink around with `strtok()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::getline()` with `\n` (the default) as the delimiter to read a whole line, and then use `std::istringstream` to parse values from each line, using `std::getline()` to read string data that is delimited by something other than spaces.

For example:

```
ifstream inFile(filename.c_str());
if (!inFile) {
    cerr << "Unable to open file" << filename;
    exit(1);   // call system to stop
}

string line;
while (getline(inFile, line))
{
    istringstream iss(line);

    getline(iss, teams[a].name, '\t');

    ...

    iss >> teams[a].wins;
    /* or:
    string temp;
    getline(iss, temp, '\t');
    istringstream(temp) >> teams[a].wins;
    */

    ... and so on  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a delimiter character to your `getline` call. `getline(inFile, line, '\t');` should work. Where `'\t'` is a tab character. Note: This only works when the elements are actually delimited by a tab

Comment: each bit of data in my txt file is seperated by tabs how do u stick the data into each field of the struct using getline like that? this will get the first bit of data but then how to i insert it

Comment: something like this????  istringstream ss(teams[i].raw);
  ss >> teams[i].name >> teams[i].wins;
  cout << teams[i].name << teams[i].wins;
  cout << endl;

Comment: The second argument of `getline` is where data will be placed. If you know what the type will be when you call `getline` then you can just use the members of your struct in place of `line` in your call to `getline` like so: `getline(inFile, teams[i].name, '\t');`

Comment: You rock thank you will try this and see if it works will be back with updates

Comment: when i try to do getline(inFile, teams[i].wins,) it says no way to convert string to an int any way to get around this or do i need to take it as a string and  cast it

Comment: `std::getline()` can only read strings. You have to use `operator>>` to read integers. So either use `inFile >> teams[i].wins`, or use something more like `getline(inFile, temp, '\t'); istringstream(temp) >> teams[i].wins;`

Comment: perfect thank you giving this a shot now this is what i was trying to do but have never used string streams before